# Why are there garbled characters in this C program output?

Tags: arrays, c, char, printf, conversion-specifier

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main() {
//    setlocale("LC_ALL","");
    unsigned char utf[]={0xe4,0xb8,0x80,0x0a};
    printf("%s",utf);
    return 0;
}
```

- The first four bytes of output are correct. The second line in the console is not expected

[image]

Comment: `%s` expects a nullterminated string. `utf` is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array is missing the null terminator strings require, so printf keeps on printing bytes beyond the end of the array until it happens upon a null byte. (Or when your program crashes due to an out of bounds access.)

Add the null byte:

```
unsigned char utf[]={0xe4,0xb8,0x80,0x0a,0x00};
```

Comment: Alternatively: `unsigned char utf[] = "\xe4\xb8\x80\x0a";` will also require 5 bytes.

Comment: thank you bro,It seems that I still need to learn more c language details

Answer (score 1):

The format `%s` expects a pointer to a string as the corresponding argument. That is the sequence of outputted characters shall be ended with the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

This array

```
unsigned char utf[]={0xe4,0xb8,0x80,0x0a};
```

does not contain a string. So you need to specify explicitly how many characters you are going to output. For example

```
printf("%.*s", 4, utf);
```